# Android TCP/IP connection over USB with linux side

Tags: android, tcp, usb

i have question about TCP/IP connection over USB between mobile phone running on Android and linux station

What i need:
create IP layer over USB between android phone and linux (PC). Phone is not rooted.

What i found:
I'm little bit searched and this solution is possible over Tethering and Mirrorlink. Mirrorlink is implementation of cdc/mc (ethernet over usb) and tethering seems to be same solution.

Another solution seems to be debug bridge adbd and adb but it is need to had enable debug mode but i am not sure with it.

Question:
It is possible to create IP layer over USB in user space through some application ?

And is possible from non rooted android phone force second side to do someting what will established the session.

Something like this:
1 step -> android phone will over usb send something to linux pc
2 step -> linux pc will create IP interface and send back over usb something to android phone (communication is still over usb)
3. step -> android phone create ip interface and communication over IP is established.

Linux pc is fully my control but android phone has limited capabilities.

Thanks for some advices.

Comment: This has been covered here quite a few times before - you cannot invent new mechanisms on a secured device, but you can use either the existing tethering or ADB capability.  Tethering has the concern of making sure not to route all the PC's traffic through the phone (unless intended) and ADB requires special settings and software and only permits inbound connections unless you add a tunneling mechanism (for example, via SSH).

Comment: Thanks for comment it have a sense (new mechanism without rooted system). ADB capabilitiy needs to have debug mode enable. This solutin is not usable for me. But tethering could be. I need only direct lan connection wihout routing the trafic. I'm able to set route table on linux machine and set the default gw to my own. I will testing tethering.

Comment: I got the idea for antoher solution. 

Establish connection only over USB with some protocol usable in user space and on the linux  side create convertor from this protocol to tcp/ip. 

It should be usable no ?

Comment: No, on a secured device you are limited to the stock USB modes.